# Would like an option to filter by language in tag filters

Tags: feature-request, tag-filters

I spend a lot of time reading questions on StackOverflow and other sites with programming related questions (200k rep) from several different custom filters I've created and these are mostly filtered by tag (Javascript, promise, node.js, etc...).  That's pretty much the only way I cull questions to look at.

But, these filters which are open to all sites are showing me more and more questions that are not in English.  Since I am not really capable in any other language, this is all just noise that gets in the way.

I understand that I could target my filter to only one specific site (like StackOverflow) where non-English questions are off-topic, but that prevents me from discovering other sites that contain relevant programming questions like the system does now.

So, I'd like to see an option in Filters to select only certain languages.

Just to be perfectly clear here, I'm talking about the filters that show up here:

[image]

And look like this when defining:

[image]

Comment: Non English questions are off topic for Stack Overflow to begin with. Just flag any of those via the review, downvote etc. (same as you do with very low quality questions you see, which can't be salvaged)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - What do I do if I want to view all Javascript tagged questions on any site that are in English?

Comment: Nothing at the moment, and don't think there will be such an option.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Allowing my tag filters to be on all sites has pulled me into 8 other sites which I am now a member of.  I guess you're saying that I have to stop having open filters if I only want English questions - that limits what other sites I will get pulled into.  You sound confident that there will not be a language option in the filter.  I'm not sure why the powers that be would be against a language filter, since the whole purpose of filters is to cull questions to those that are relevant to what you can help with.  Language is as critical as any other criteria.  Any idea why?

Comment: I thought you were talking only about Stack Overlow, where only English is allowed. What other sites you mean? And how can you review cross site? All in all, I no longer understand what you really ask here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I'm using Filters that select recent questions by tag (e.g. all questions with the "Javascript" tag).  These filters have an option to apply to ONLY specific sites that you list or to all sites.  Because I like discovering new sites that contain questions relevant to the tags I'm interested in, I have all my filters set to All Sites.  For example, this is how I got pulled into the codereview site because there are "Javascript" tagged questions there.  So, what I'd like is to figure out how to make the filters work for  "All Sites in English" or "All Questions in English".

Comment: Here's [an example of a non-English question](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444470/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B9-div-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5) that shows up in my "Javascript" filter.

Comment: My bad, your word "reviewing" and your mention of high rep on SO confused me, thought you mean review tasks. Retagged now.

Comment: Anyway, while such option doesn't exist, this can be a valid feature request. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Sorry about that.  I tried to clarify the question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - so do I retag as a feature request or does it have to re-edited into a feature request or start a new post for a feature request?  I've never quite felt comfortable with the procedures here on Meta is why I'm asking.

Comment: Yes and change the title and body to reflect it e.g. "Add an option to exclude non-English sites in tag filters"

Comment: Question changed from a support question to a feature request.

Comment: I support this feature request.

Comment: Just to be clear: There is a site [pt.stackoverflow.com](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/) (Portuguese) and [ru.stackoverflow.com](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/) (Russian). These sites allow, of course, non-English language. A language filter would be great, as it would still allow the option "All Sites" but exclude non wanted language sites.

Comment: It's a bummer that this is STILL a problem I encounter daily on my tag filters.  I searched on Google for a solution and ended up pointed to my own feature-request here from 7 years ago.